# is application cache storage space is limited for each domain

Tags: application-cache

I am having a silly doubt about the HTML5 app cache. Here is the question: if i am using application cache in a both **domain 1** , and **domain 2** . if **domain 1** uses 4.9MB and **domain 2** wants to store 2MB data. Is it possible to store?  where actually the app-cache stores the data? in Hard disc or somewhere???

Answer (score -1):

Cache store the data in the Ram on the server side. It depends on your server capacity how much cache it can store.

Comment: I am not asking about cache asking about **Application cache**. This is used for offline web application. Then how it stores the data in server????

Comment: got an information: The browser gives 5MB separately for each domain. storage of **Domain 1** will not affect **domain 2**. Web storage provides far greater storage capacity (5MB per domain in Mozilla Firefox,[6] Google Chrome, and Opera, 10MB per storage area in Internet Explorer[7]) compared to 4KB (around 1000 times less space) available to cookies.